# Object creation not assigned to variable

Tags: memory-management, delphi-10.3-rio

I'd like to use a method of a class without assigning its creation to a variable. For example:

```
type
  TMyObject = class
  public
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

implementation

procedure MyObjDoesSomething;
begin
  TMyObject.Create.DoSomething;
end;

{ TMyObject }

procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
begin
  // ...
end;
```

As you can see, in `MyObjDoesSomething` I didn't assign `TMyObject.Create` to a `TMyObject` variable.

Does this have some kind of impact on memory usage, or even something else I did't think of?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you don't want to use a local variable?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I answered under Remy Lebeau's answer

Comment: What seems to be clear is that there is more to this problem that the code in the question. It seems like you have a problem, but it's not expressed by the code here. You should do what Remy says and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you `Create` an object to allocate memory for it, you must call `Free()` on the object when you are done using it to release that memory, otherwise the memory is leaked, which will impact memory over time if you create these objects multiple times.

If you don't want to use an explicit variable to refer to the object (why?), you can use a `with` block, eg:

```pascal
procedure MyObjDoesSomething;
begin
  with TMyObject.Create do
  try
    DoSomething;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Another option is to make the class implement an `interface`, and then you can let the compiler's reference counting of interfaces handle freeing the object for you. This has a little bit more overhead than above, but you don't have to worry as much about handling the memory manually, eg:

```pascal
type
  IMyObject = interface
    ['{896FF4FA-A974-4A8B-9EA5-414C138635E4}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyObject)
  public
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

implementation

procedure MyObjDoesSomething;
begin
  (TMyObject.Create as IMyObject).DoSomething;
end;

{ TMyObject }

procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
begin
  // ...
end;
```

But really, just use a variable instead. It costs you nothing to use:

```pascal
procedure MyObjDoesSomething;
var
  Obj;
begin
  Obj := TMyObject.Create;
  try
    Obj.DoSomething;
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: With construct is frequently discouraged. Actually it is a controversial subject.

Comment: @fpiette yes, but in simple cases like this, the controversial issues it can cause are fairly moot.

Comment: This isn't really the usage for with though is it. That the issues are moot in a didactic example is missing the point. It's the nitty gritty real world brownfield maintenance issues that matter.

Comment: In my real environment, `TMyObject.DoSomething` uses RTTI to assign one of his methods to an event property of another object. If I call `Free` after `DoSomething`, I get Access Violation when the other object's event fires, so I was wondering if calling `DoSomething` as I did in my example could be a workaround... Implementing the interface didn't solve the problem, so I decided to store the `TMyObject` (instead of having a local variable) and free it when the other object is destroyed.

Comment: @MarinaFinetti "*If I call `Free` after `DoSomething`, I get Access Violation when the other object's event fires*" - make sense, if you are `Free`ing the object that owns the method being used for the event handler, and that method tries to access members of that object via its `Self` pointer. "*Implementing the interface didn't solve the problem*" - if you use an interfaced object for the event handler, you have to take extra measures to ensure the object's refcount does not fall to 0 while the object is assigned to the event. Basically, the same issue - premature destruction of the object

Comment: @MarinaFinetti it would be really useful if you would edit your question to provide a more accurate [mcve] of the actual situation you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a big impact: A nice memory leak!

You call the constructor of an object but never free the created object. Each time you'll call your MyObjDoesSomething, you'll leak an object instance.

To solve that problem, you could make a class method of DoSomething like this:

```
type
  TMyObject = class
  public
    class procedure DoSomething;
  end;
```

Then you can call DoSomething without creating an object like this:

```
procedure MyObjDoesSomething;
begin
  TMyObject.DoSomething;
end;
```

Being a class method, DoSomething implementation cannot use object instance variables (fields).